# Function is not adding information to my dictionary

Tags: python

So I've got my functions created like so:

```
def create_contact(contacts, first, last, email, age, phone):
   """
   Creates a contact.
   """

   contacts[(first, last)] = [email, age, phone]


def contains_contact(contacts, first, last):
    """
    Checks to see if the dictionary contains  a contact.
    """
    if (first.lower(), last.lower()) in contacts == True:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)
```

and then at the bottom of my code I have my main function like so:

```
def main():
   # The Dictionary
   contacts = {}
   # Provided Test Code
   create_contact(contacts, "Katie", "Katz", "katie.katz@gmail.com",
               25, "857-294-2758")
   #Checks to see if item in dictionary exists
   print("Creation of Katie Katz: {}".format(
    "Passed" if contains_contact(contacts, "Katie", "kaTz") else
    "Failed"))
```

I’m not sure where I’m going wrong. It seems as though the items are not being added to my dictionary. Unsure as to why, maybe I’m attempting this all wrong.

Comment: You don’t lower case the names in the key tuple. You can just `print(contacts)` to see the function *is* adding the information. Also your second method should just be `return (first.lower(), last.lower()) in contacts`.

Comment: return in create_contact is missing

Comment: @DineshPundkar it mutates its parameter, to return something as well is not conventional in Python.

Comment: It's just as jonrsharpe put it: python string comparison is case sensitive so the lower case key is different from the not-lowercase one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adding of items to your dict is working fine, however you forgot to convert the first and last name to lowercase in `create_contact`. You did do it in `contains_contact` however, which is why your code doesn't work.

```
def create_contact(contacts, first, last, email, age, phone):
   """
   Creates a contact.
   """

   contacts[(first.lower(), last.lower())] = [email, age, phone]
```

Additionally, your `contains_contact` function could be simplified:

```
def contains_contact(contacts, first, last):
    """
    Checks to see if the dictionary contains  a contact.
    """
    return (first.lower(), last.lower()) in contacts
```

Comment: You don't need the `()`. It should be like this `contacts[first.lower(), last.lower()] = [email, age, phone]`

Comment: @sdikby You're right, but correcting that wouldn't contribute anything to answering the question. There are a lot of things about the code the OP posted that are suboptimal, but this is not codereview

Comment: that's why i commented on your answer and not his. You gave an answer which was accepted. It's worth the little extra effort to remove those `()` and add something like "... they are useless in this case...". I personally like "pythonic"-correct answers.

Comment: @sdikby If you go so far as to suggest the edit, okay, so be it :) However please note that there is a lot of discussion on meta about this, such as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266572/answer-question-or-improve-code). Generally, the consensus seems to be that we can't teach people to write good code by improving it in the answers, it has to be learned _the hard way_, and I think I agree. The most important aspect of an answer on SO is to actually answer the question.